# Will repeatedly fine-tuning on new data cause overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, overfitting

I have a binary classification model which I have trained on a training set. On the validation set its accuracy is ~85%. I set up early stopping which ended training when validation loss increased. Let's call this final model `modelA`.

Because of the nature of the task I can generate as much training data as I want. I have a huge dataset (say, reddit comments) and am generating positive and negative examples in a way that there are an astronomical number of combinations. So I'm not worried that the model is "memorizing" my training data.

So I generated another dataset and fine-tuned `modelA` until the early stopping trigger was fired. The validation accuracy of this model, `modelB`, was ~87%.

I repeated the process once more, getting a final validation accuracy of ~89% for `modelC`.

My question is, will this cause overfitting? Is this iterative fine-tuning a common industry practice?

Answer (score 0):

There could be an overfitting issue indeed. Models shouldn't constantly increase their accuracy with additional trainings, and it could result as a bad generalization, i.e. a failure in classifying new combinations.

I don't know if your model uses neural networks, but if it is so, there are several functions to forget/reset a small part of the trained neurons, so that it avoids overfitting in new trainings. The [Dropout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilution_(neural_networks)) function is the most common one, but you could have similar functions in error calculation functions like the [Adam Optimization](https://optimization.cbe.cornell.edu/index.php?title=Adam).

If there is no such functions in your model, a solution could to restart from scratch the training including the new data. If the result is similar to model A, it could confirm that model B and C were overfitting.

Finally, overfitting results highly depends on data, Model C could also be correct without overfitting, more details would be necessary to check this out. But generally speaking if you are around 90% or more, you are in an overfitting scenario.